# What animation techniques and styles in Arcane contribute to this enhanced realism?

Tags: film-techniques, animation, arcane

In Netflix's *Arcane*, the action scenes appear notably more realistic and engaging compared to other animated series, such as 'Marvel's What If...?'. What animation techniques and styles in *Arcane* contribute to this enhanced realism and impact?

Comment: mo-cap and photo-realism, presumably.

Comment: @Valorum It wasn't *that* kind of realism, more of a detailed, artistic look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arcane used combination of 2D and 3D, from [mashable](https://mashable.com/article/netflix-arcane-league-of-legends-animation)

> "In a typical 3D production, every element from the characters to the
> background is modelled in three dimensions," Barthelemy Maunoury,
> Fortiche's director of animation for Arcane, explained to Mashable.
>
> "On Arcane, it’s slightly different — the backgrounds are digitally
> hand-painted and the texture on the characters is crafted to get that
> graphical look that fits with the environment. We also mainly use 2D
> animation for the FXs (explosions, tears, smoke...) to reinforce the
> painted look. In the details it’s slightly more complicated but it’s
> more or less how you end up with something that looks like an
> illustration."

If you compare it with something like Marvel's Wjat If, from [screenrant](https://screenrant.com/marvel-what-if-animation-style-cel-shading-controversy-explained/#:%7E:text=Marvel%27s%20What%20If...%3F%20uses%20cel-shading%20animation%20like%20the,and%20is%20praised%20for%20its%20comic%20book-like%20aesthetic.)

> Marvel's What If...? uses cel-shading animation like the aforementioned Spider-Man series, involving rendering 3D objects to appear more 2D or cartoon-like. It's a technique that is mostly associated with video games and is praised for its comic book-like aesthetic.

From Cel shading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading) page:

> Cel shading or toon shading is a type of non-photorealistic rendering designed to make 3-D computer graphics appear to be flat by using less shading color instead of a shade gradient or tints and shades. A cel shader is often used to mimic the style of a comic book or cartoon and/or give the render a characteristic paper-like texture.

So it looks like both used 3D but Arcane mixed 2D to give it its distinct look but What IF made the 3D look flatter for a comic booky look.